# Why do I have to publish MVC project twice?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I have noticed that when I am publishing an MVC project to a 2008R2 IIS server I have to do it twice in a row.

I am publishing by file system, and have selected to Delete all existing files prior to publish and precompile during publishing.

IIS and the site is setup to use Windows Auth.

If I only publish once and browse to the site I receive a 403 Forbidden Access error.

Comment: Have you checked your event logs/IIS logs for details of the error?

Comment: I have but not in a while, so I don't remember if there was something in them.  I will perform another publish when I get a chance.  When I do publish I have just made it an extra step to publish a second time.